# Flash - How to capture blocks 4096 from Microphone

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio-recording

I'm trying to record from user's microphone on Internet Explorer. But, one of my thousand problems is that, blocks of data coming from flash engine, on each cycle, is **always multiple** of 2048 bytes. [2048, 6144, 4096, 2048, etc...].

When recording on other browsers, using native AudioContext, each event cycle generate **exactly a single block** of 4096 bytes.

Some one know a way to enforce flash to capture always blocks of 4096. Or, just to force flash chunks to be multiple of 4096?

The problem is, when buffering all this data, on flash, sometimes, I get the last block of 2048. And if I add an empty block of 2048 to match 4096, I will get a small silence time on the end.

This is my Microphone configuration:

```
mic.rate = Math.floor(sampleRate / 1000); // Conversion go khz
mic.gain = 50;
mic.setSilenceLevel(0);
mic.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, processBuffer); // Function to process each event.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why is it so important to you to receive the data in blocks of 4096 bytes? Is there any data missing? It seems like all you want to do is collect all data, which should be possible regardless of the block size.

Comment: but the sound could end in the middle of 4096 block so you will get silence time anyway, no?

Comment: Hi Andrei. Chrome and Firefox only stops a record session when last buffer size reach 4096 bytes, and if I stop em play instantly, I have no data loss. My desire is to respect the same behavior with flash.